# Adding a custom certificate to an OkHttp Client

Tags: java, android, ssl, okhttp

I am trying to make Android app, where I can get and parse HTML (from site which doesnt have API). I am using OkHttp. The site has untrusted (but valid) certificate. I am getting:

```
java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
```

I've already set up the official way (https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl#java) and now I need to link it with OkHttpClient.

I tried

```
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient;

    OkHttpClient.Builder builder = client.newBuilder();
    builder.sslSocketFactory(sslcontext.getSocketFactory()).build();
```

But it doesnt work, and also it is deprecated.
Thanks

Comment: check here. https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-trust-unsafe-ssl-certificates-self-signed-expired

Answer (score -4, accepted):

**Only use for debugging. Using this code means trusting any certificate which is as good as not using https at all.**

---

You need to use `sslSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory, X509TrustManager trustManager)` which is not deprecated.

Use this variable (which creates a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains):

```
TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] {
    new X509TrustManager() {
        @Override
        public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
        }

        @Override
        public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
        }

        @Override
        public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return new java.security.cert.X509Certificate[]{};
        }
    }
};
```

and pass to `sslSocketFactory()` in this way:

```
builder.sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory, (X509TrustManager)trustAllCerts[0]);
```

also apply this to verify every host:

```
builder.hostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
    @Override
    public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: This is bad _standard_ advice.  The original report says that it has "untrusted (but valid) certificate" so the solution should be to add that certificate or a signing CA certificate in the chain to the truststore.  And the question title is "OkHTTP Client add custom certificate"

Comment: @YuriSchimke I usually have a check for production/pre-production/development. I use this parts of code only for debugging purpose, of course not in production.

Answer (score 16):

See this documented example for adding a known trusted certificate

https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/samples/guide/src/main/java/okhttp3/recipes/CustomTrust.java

```
  public CustomTrust() {
    X509TrustManager trustManager;
    SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory;
    try {
      trustManager = trustManagerForCertificates(trustedCertificatesInputStream());
      SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
      sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[] { trustManager }, null);
      sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
    } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory, trustManager)
        .build();
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

OkHttp 4.7.1 supports specific insecure hosts for development only

https://square.github.io/okhttp/changelog/

https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/482f88300f78c3419b04379fc26c3683c10d6a9d/samples/guide/src/main/java/okhttp3/recipes/kt/DevServer.kt

```
  val clientCertificates = HandshakeCertificates.Builder()
      .addPlatformTrustedCertificates()
      .addInsecureHost(server.hostName)
      .build()

  val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
      .sslSocketFactory(clientCertificates.sslSocketFactory(), clientCertificates.trustManager)
      .build()
```