# Enabling HTTPS communication between my server and my client

Tags: android, ssl, https, certificate, okhttp

I have already built a server app and an android app. So far they were communicating over http, but I am sending sensitive information in each request (like JWT). Therefore I neet to use Https instead.

I have generated a p12 certificate.

On the server side:

1. I've copied the certificate to `resources/keystore/sampleName.p12`
2. I've added these lines to my `application.properties`

   ```
   server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
   server.ssl.key-store-password=samplePassword
   server.ssl.key-store=classpath:keystore/sampleName.p12
   server.ssl.key-alias=sampleName
   ```

On android side I use okHttp and create the client like this

```
val httpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .certificatePinner(
        CertificatePinner.Builder()
            .add(
                https://10.0.2.2:8080,
                "sha256/lVIcG+gpmlabsq1bW5RbvB+kqVSHKdOFyoxjo9+SLEs="
            ).build()
    )
    .build()
```

I use `https://10.0.2.2:8080` because I run the server app only localy and I also run the android app on an emulator on the same laptop.

To get `sha256/lVIcG+gpmlabsq1bW5RbvB+kqVSHKdOFyoxjo9+SLEs=` I've used `keytool -list -v -keystore sampleName.p12 -storetype PKCS12 -storepass samplePassword` and converted the sha256 fingerprint which was in hex to base64.

Now when I try to send any request to the server I get an

`javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found`

I am clearly missing something but I dont know what. Is there anything else I need to do? Or did I do something wrong? Or is it just not supposed to work localy?

Note that this is just an exercise for me and I won't be actually deploying the server app on any real server and I won't release the android app.

But still I will be presenting the solution and I really nedd it to be solid and work localy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CertificatePinning is in addition to the normal certificate checks.  It only further restricts the choice of certificate, since be default you will accept any cert for your host.

See [Adding a custom certificate to an OkHttp Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53304082/adding-a-custom-certificate-to-an-okhttp-client) for an existing answer.

Or read up here

https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/samples/guide/src/main/java/okhttp3/recipes/CustomTrust.java

https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-certificate-pinner/

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have modified the CustomTrust class to have a getter for the okHttpClient and hardcoded my certificat to it. Now I am getting the httpClient as CustomTrust().client. This is a good enough solutin for me. Thank you again