# React native fetch on android against local RestAPI with self signed SSL certificate

Tags: android, react-native, ssl, okhttp

Is there a way to ignore the self signed ssl as react native is using okHTTP3 on android under the hood and its not allowed to fetch from self signed SSL APIs, in my case its going to be always a local RestAPI and it will run on the local network. what is the workaround?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify in your dev build that a particular host is insecure

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/61884408/1542667

https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp-tls/okhttp3.tls/-handshake-certificates/-builder/add-insecure-host/

Comment: I am using expo with react native and i dont know how to do it there

Comment: I think this provides access https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/modules/network/OkHttpClientProvider.java

Answer (score 0):

In the end i used HTTP with clear type in the android manifest file.

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```